# Error trying to set an array value that is a property of a class in c#

Tags: c#

`object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`

I'm getting the above error in my code and I cant figure out why (there are many similar questions but all I've read seems to be relevant to me).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        VenueMappings venueMappings = new VenueMappings();
        var venue1 = new Venue
        {
            ExtEventNo = 1,
            UsiVenue = "building1",
        };

        VenueMappings.venues[0] = venue1;
    }
}

public struct Venue
{
    public int ExtEventNo;
    public String UsiVenue;
};


public class VenueMappings
{
    public Venue[] venues = new Venue[2];  
};
```

Comment: Side note: R/W field (or even property) of collection type is dangerous as one can simply replace whole collection and your class may not be prepared for that. Consider `public List<Venue> {get; private set;}` (and initialization in constructor) as alternative approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using class name `VenueMappings`, but you should be using variable `venueMappings`. You can reference static properies and methods via class name, but you can reference only instance properties and methods via instance.

Replace

```
VenueMappings.venues[0] = venue1;
```

with

```
venueMappings.venues[0] = venue1;
```

Comment: Thanks, cant believe I didn't notice that.